# Loop over each item in a row and compare with each item from another row then save the result in a new column_python

Tags: python, loops, row, items

I want to loop in python, over each item from a row against other items from the correspondent row from another column.
If item is not present in the row of the second column then should append to the new list that will be converted in another column (this should also eliminate duplicates when appending through if i not in c).

The goal is to compare items from each row of a column against items from the correspondent row in another column and to save the unique values from the first column, in a new column same df.

[df columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36lPG.png)

This is just an example, I have much many items in each row

I tried using this code but nothing happened and conversion of the list into the column it's not correct from what I have tested

```
a= df['final_key_concat'].tolist()
b = df['attributes_tokenize'].tolist()
c = []
for i in df.values:
    for i in a:
        if i in a:
            if i not in b:
                if i not in c:
                    c.append(i)
                    print(c)
                    df['new'] = pd.Series(c)
```

Any help is more than needed, thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just write paste you data and codes here instead of sharing images.

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image.

Comment: really sorry about it, I just modified that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    def parse_str_into_list(s):
    if s.startswith('[') and s.endswith(']'):
        return ' '.join(s.strip('[]').strip("'").split("', '"))
    return s

def filter_restrict_words(row):
    targets = parse_str_into_list(row[0]).split(' ', -1)
    restricts = parse_str_into_list(row[1]).split(' ', -1)
    print(restricts)

    # start for loop each words
    # use set type to save words or  list if we need to keep words in order
    words_to_keep = []
    for word in targets:
        # condition to keep eligible words
        if word not in restricts and 3 < len(word) < 45 and word not in words_to_keep:
            words_to_keep.append(word)
            print(words_to_keep)

    return ' '.join(words_to_keep)

df['FINAL_KEYWORDS'] = df[[col_target, col_restrict]].apply(lambda x: filter_restrict_words(x), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

So seeing as you have these two variables one way would be:

```
a= df['final_key_concat'].tolist()
b = df['attributes_tokenize'].tolist()
```

Try something like this:

```
new = {}
for index, items in enumerate(a):
    for thing in items:
        if thing not in b[index]:
            if index in new:
                new[index].append(thing)
            else:
                new[index] = [thing]
```

Then map the dictionary to the df.

```
df['new'] = df.index.map(new)
```

There are better ways to do it but this should work.

Comment: I have tried that before too, it only brings the values from final_key_concat into df['new_column'], whithout excluding items present in  attribute_tokenize

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! This is actually taking the characters not present in the second row, at least eliminates whats not present  in the row that gets to be compared but by char and not word

Comment: You will have to post part of your dataframe its difficult to do without

Comment: Unfortunately there I cant post it, its just the data from the image in the description, two columns and the error i get after using your method is                                                   for thing in items:
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: replacing with str(items) and  str(b[index]) it works but again, the output are characters not words

Comment: I don't know what you mean i have just ran the code and it works. Print the new df and you will see

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you want:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'final_key_concat':[['Camiseta', 'Tecnica', 'hombre', 'barate'], 
['deportivas', 'calcetin', 'hombres', 'deportivas', 'shoes']],
    'attributes_tokenize':[['The', 'North', 'Face', 'manga'], ['deportivas', 
'calcetin', 'shoes', 'North']]} #recreated from your image

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

a= df['final_key_concat'].tolist() #this generates a list of lists
b = df['attributes_tokenize'].tolist()#this also generates a list of lists
#Both list a and b need to be flattened so as to access their elements the way you want it
c = [itm for sblst in a for itm in sblst] #flatten list a using list comprehension
d = [itm for sblst in b for itm in sblst] #flatten list b using list comprehension

final_list = [itm for itm in c if itm not in d]#Sort elements common to both list c and d

print (final_list)
```

> Result

```
['Camiseta', 'Tecnica', 'hombre', 'barate', 'hombres']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately the output contains common words and I need to extract unique values from the first column (final_key_concat), values that are not found in the second column

Comment: I have modified this line into                                                               final_list = [itm for itm in c if itm not in d]#Sort elements common to both list c and d  and it looks like it worked, will test with more data  but I will have to assign the final list to a column

Comment: @Isa i modifed my code 13 mins ago, its possible you didn't take note.

Comment: thanks a ton! One last question, I tried to assign the list to a column with  df['new'] = pd.Series(final_list) but it only inserts values in a singke row, any idea what Im doing wrong?   Again, many thankx for your help

Comment: df['new'] = pd.Series([final_list])

Comment: it still inserts all the resulted items in a single row

Comment: Also, when I use my file directly as df =pd.read_excel(r'C:\Test2\test.xlsx',encoding='ISO-8859-1')

a= df['final_key_concat'].tolist()
b = df['attributes_tokenize'].tolist()
 the result are characters and not the words like in your example when you have created df from dictionary

Comment: Why do you prefer Latin-1(8859-1) encoding to UTF8?

Comment: Because with UTF8 my file cant be read, returns an error

Comment: Sorry to bother you so much @Seyi Daniel, do you have any idea why the version you sent its working with the dictionary you ve created but not with the file directly? Also, how can be done correctly the conversion from list to column? Many thanks again for your input

Comment: You may share some portion of you input file if you don't mind. Maybe if i get to see the content, I'll be able to give some advice.

Comment: The file I'm testing this is exactly as in the image, unfortunately I cant paste data here excepting add the image but the data looks like in the dict you ve created  when I use your code returns: c = [itm for sblst in a for itm in sblst]                                          TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable                                                                                         Occurs when I read the data from the file, using your method with the dictionary converted into df, it works. The new column also insert al the list in a single row